# What would be a good synonym for the word "stamp" in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, synonyms

> The intense suffering of this experience left a lasting stamp on Dostoevsky’s mind.

(the author talks about Dostoevsky's experience of being condemned to death and then spared at the last minute by his Majesty)

I know that one of the synonyms for the word stamp is "mark" but I don't know if it can be used when referring to people as I couldn't find any examples or definitions stating that.

Answer (score 3):

In this case a synonym for "stamp" is "impression," like the shape *pressed* into a blob of sealing wax by a personal stamp:

[image: image of a blob of red sealing wax pressed with a rose design, and the stamp used to make the design]

The idiom is "to have something pressed into one's mind" or "...imprinted on one's mind." It means that the experience is strongly remembered and has a long-term effect on the person, as if something had physically stamped the information or memory onto the person's brain.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious alternative is “impression.”

Comment: We sometimes say that a traumatic experience 'marked someone for life'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey We do indeed, but I have not heard “mark someone’s mind.” That is the problem with set phrases; some variations seem pleasing, and others just sound weird.